# Enumeration For Application.InputBox

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I use `Application.InputBox()` I bring up VBA Help to remind me which `Type` to use:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String

    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter data", Type:=2)
End Sub
```

Does there exist, or can I create an Enumeration for `Type` so I could code like:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String

    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter data", Type:=vbString)
End Sub
```

It would be easier for me to remember an Enumeration rather than an arbitrary integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't, but you can just create an enumeration by yourself:

```
Public Enum InputBoxType
    ibtFormula = 0
    ibtNumber = 1
    ibtText = 2
    ibtBoolean = 4
    ibtRange = 8
    ibtError = 16
    ibtArray = 64
End Enum
```

Comment: Can also have combinations like this: `ibtNumOrText = 1 + 2`

Comment: Sure but then you would have to add 64 values to the enum for all combinations (ibtFormula appears to be implicitely included because it's zero). It makes much more sense to use `ibtNumber + ibtText` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Using IntelliSense**

As the main intention seems to be fastening inputs without consulting extra help,
I'd propose to benefit from using *IntelliSense*:

Simply start input within a code module by

```
vba.VbVarType.
```

or in the immediate window by

```
?vba.VbVarType.
```

and choose the proposed DropDown values:

[image: Using Intellisense]

Alternatively you could have a look into the Object Browser, too giving a better overview.